# Pandas pivot_table - How to make a MultiIndex from a mix of column values and column names?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I'm relatively new to Pandas. I have a DataFrame in the form:

```python
         A         B       C            D         E
0        1       1.1       a      23.7853   18.2647
1        1       1.2       a      23.7118   17.2387
2        1       1.1       b      24.1873   17.3874
3        1       1.2       b      23.1873   18.1748
4        2       1.1       a      24.1872   18.1847
...      ...     ...       ...     ...       ...
```

I would like to pivot it to have a three-level MultiIndex constructed from the values in columns A and B and the column headers ["D", "E"]. I also want to use the values from B as the new column headers and the data in columns D and E for the values. All values are one-to-one (with some NaNs). If I understand correctly, I need to use pivot_table() instead of just pivot() because of the MultiIndex. Ultimately I want a table that looks like:

```python
B                      1.1       1.2  ...
A    C  col-name
1    a         D   23.7853   23.7118  ...
               E   18.2647   17.2387  ...
     b         D   24.1873   23.1873  ...
               E   17.3874   18.1748  ...
2    a         D   24.1872   23.1987  ...
               E   18.1847   19.2387  ...
...  ...     ...     ...       ...    ...
```

I'm pretty sure the answer is to use some command like

```python
pd.pivot_table(df, columns=["B"], values=["D","E"], index=["A","C","???"])
```

I'm unsure what to put in the "values" and "index" arguments to get the right behavior.

If I can't do this with a single pivot_table command, do I need to construct my Multi-Index ahead of time? Then what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a multiindex with columns `A, C, B` then use **[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)** + **[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)** to reshape the dataframe

```
df.set_index(['A', 'C', 'B']).stack().unstack(-2)
```

---

```
B          1.1      1.2
A C                    
1 a D  23.7853  23.7118
    E  18.2647  17.2387
  b D  24.1873  23.1873
    E  17.3874  18.1748
2 a D  24.1872      NaN
    E  18.1847      NaN
```

Comment: It looks like after stacking, the correct index for unstack is actually -3 instead of -2. This did exactly what I wanted:
`df.set_index(['A', 'C', 'B']).stack().unstack(-3)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) together with [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), as follows:

```
(pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'C'], columns='B', values=["D","E"])
   .rename_axis(columns=['col_name', 'B'])         # set axis name for ["D","E"] 
   .stack(level=0)
)
```

**Result:**

```
B                 1.1      1.2
A C col_name                  
1 a D         23.7853  23.7118
    E         18.2647  17.2387
  b D         24.1873  23.1873
    E         17.3874  18.1748
2 a D         24.1872      NaN
    E         18.1847      NaN
```

Comment: This works, but I accepted @Shubham Sharma's answer because it is both more concise and seems to run faster on my large dataset. Thanks!